# How to pass CloudFormation's WaitHandle to a different Cloud Formation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Due to limits on the number of resources in a cloud formation stack, we need to have multiple stacks, where our main stack launches several other smaller substacks. We have wait conditions that are created in the main stack, which need to be passed to resources in some of the sub stacks. Currently, we have the entire substack wait on the WaitHandle, instead of the individual resources within the substack. However, this unnecessarily increases our launch times by a significant amount. 
To solve this, I've tried passing the WaitHandle as a Parameter to the substack, but I wasn't sure what the parameter's type would be. 
I've also heard my coworker say that you could try passing the WaitHandle's URL as a string, and then trying to create a new WaitHandle with that url within the substacks, but I don't see any documentation on that. 
Is what I'm trying to do even possible in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For passing the WaitHandle URL as a string to your substack, according to the [AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitconditionhandle.html) documentation,

> When you reference the `WaitConditionHandle` resource by using the `Ref` function, AWS CloudFormation returns a presigned URL. You pass this URL to applications or scripts that are running on your Amazon EC2 instances to send signals to that URL.

There are actually two different ways to accomplish your goal:

1. Pass `{"Ref": "MyWaitHandle"}` as a parameter to your substack, then have the resource/s in your substack include this parameter (e.g., using `${ParentWaitHandle}` within a [`Fn::Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) string) as the presigned URL to send a 'Wait Condition Signal' to, using an HTTP PUT request (e.g. with `cURL`, as used in the [Creating Wait Conditions in a Template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-waitcondition.html) walkthrough):

`curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type:' --data-binary '{"Status": "SUCCESS", "Reason": "Configuration Complete","UniqueId": "$UNIQUE_ID", "Data": "Application has completed configuration."}' "${ParentWaitHandle}"`

2. Pass only the `WaitCondition` resource name instead to the substack (via `Ref`), and use the [`SignalResource`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_SignalResource.html) CloudFormation service API call to signal the `WaitCondition` resource directly. This lets you skip dealing with separate `WaitConditionHandle` resources, but requires `cloudformation:SignalResource` IAM permission to be granted to the signalling resource to make the API call. For example, using the AWS CLI:

`aws cloudformation signal-resource \
  --status SUCCESS \
  --unique-id $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) \
  --logical-resource-id ${ParentWaitCondition} \
  --stack-name $PARENT_STACK \
  --region ${AWS::Region} \
  || true`

Comment: I need to do it the opposite way, where the waithandle is resolved in the main stack, but a resource in the substack depends on a condition  of the waithandle. I tried passing in the wait handle as a parameter and creating a waitcondition from the passed in handle in the substack, but AWS gave me an error saying that you can't wait on a WaitHandle Url from a different stack.

Comment: It sounds like the problem you're really looking to solve is not "How to pass CloudFormation's WaitHandle to a different Cloud Formation stack," but rather "how to have a nested stack resource depend on a resource in a parent stack," which is really quite different. I believe I've answered the question stated, for the new question I suggest you create a new SO question and describe your question more clearly.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll ask the question on the AWS forums as well and see if I get a response. Although, I've now tried creating a WaitCondition in a substack with a wait handle url that was passed in as a parameter from another stack. This resulted in "Cannot wait on specified Handle URL - handle must originate from within the same stack".